# What to web.xml in a project consits of , Do intially the server starts with web.xml file ?.

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets, web.xml

What to web.xml in a project consits of , Do intially the server starts with web.xml file ?.  If i am using any framework in ma project , how it has been called from web.xml file. Could you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ever the technology you are using for the web application web.xml is like a heart

First the server checks for the web.xml and calls the very first file from the welcome list tag used in the web.xml and then afterwards it will continue with the technology what you are using like sevlets, struts so on..